# Is there any overhead to define complicated (large size) class inside another class?

Tags: c++

To make my question clear, I'll give a simplified example:

```
class Foo {
public:
    class Bar {
        int garbage[1000000];
    };
    void playWithGarbage() {
         //whatever...
    }
 }
```

Now, if I generate a lot of instances of Foo and pass them around by value or reference. Will there be any significant overhead? I tested the size, and it's OK: `sizeof(Foo)` returns 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will be no overhead for objects of type `Foo`. `Foo` simply acts like a namespace in which `Bar` is contained. The existence of `Foo::Bar` objects is independent of the existence of `Foo` objects. If `Foo` had a `Bar` member, however, then objects of type `Foo` would have subobjects of type `Bar` and therefore have an increased size.